# UI Automation: Tap on table view cell that’s off screen

Tags: ui-automation

When I try and tap on a table view cell that’s off screen I get:

```
Debug: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[16] could not be tapped
Error: Script threw an uncaught JavaScript error: target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[0].cells()[16] could not be tapped
```

What’s the best way to get this cell on-screen? Should I use a dragInsideWithOptions or scrollToVisible?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `scrollToVisible()` on the cell.

Example:

```
var cell = tableView.cells()[5];
cell.scrollToVisible();
```